# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have used this method for GraphQL mutations and it works but I'm having an issue with Graphql queries.

```
 export default interface LoadUsersResponse {
    users: {
        nodes:{
            id: Number;
            firstName: String;
            lastName: String;
            email: String;
            phoneNumber: String;
          }
          totalCount: Number;
    };
  }

const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery<LoadUsersResponse>(LoadUsersQuery);
```

I run the query like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => ShowUsers()}>
          {' '}
          Search
        </Button>
        <br></br>
        <PrintUsers data={data} />
```

```
function PrintUsers({ data }: LoadUsersResponse) {
    return (
      <div>
        {data &&
          data.users.nodes &&
          data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
            <li key={i}>
              Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
              Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I get an error on `data`in the first line that:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'LoadUsersResponse'.ts(2339)
```

Though it works fine If I completely remove the UserResponse type and just write `any`here.

If I remove the deconstructing and keep using LoadUserResponse, I get an error on the word map in PrintUsers that

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ id: Number; firstName: String; lastName: String; email: String; phoneNumber: String; }'.ts(2339)
```

and here `<PrintUsers data={data} />`
I get an error on first `data`that

```
Type '{ data: LoadUsersResponse | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LoadUsersResponse'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LoadUsersResponse'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2):

When typing `({ data }: LoadUsersResponse)` you are deconstructing the object in the initializer. Replacing it with `( data: LoadUsersResponse)` should solve your (first) issue. I am not able to answer why it compiles with `any` though...

Then you're attempting to `map` an `Object`, which is not feasible. Perhaps this is what you want to achieve:

```
interface NodeProps {
  id: Number;
  firstName: String;
  lastName: String;
  email: String;
  phoneNumber: String;
}

export default interface LoadUsersResponse {
  users: {
    nodes: NodeProps[];
    totalCount: Number;
  };
}

function PrintUsers(data: LoadUsersResponse) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.users.nodes &&
        data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
          <li key={i}>
            Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
            Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
          </li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Some additional thoughts, there's no reason to check for undefined `data &&` as you're explicitly expecting it. It will always be there. And also it's preferable to use literal `string` above JS `String`.

Comment: that doesn't work for me. Could you please see the updated qs?

Comment: Well, now you're trying to `map` a `string`. `map` is an `Array` method. Perhaps `nodes` should be an array of objects with those properties instead?

Comment: How is it a string? data should be the object returned the graphql query. How can I modify the nodes then?

Comment: Sorry, my error, I meant to say you're trying to `map` an object. Still, this need's to be of `Array` type of you want to `map` it, which deriving from your usage of it, seems to be the case. I updated my answer with what I guess the solution is.